# How to plot Loglinear histogram in mathematica for x and y data

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have an `x` and `y` data, `x` is in log scale and `y` is in linear scale. I am trying to plot the histogram between these two data. How to do it? and also how to customize the width of the individual rectangle of the histogram. Below is How I tried

```
data={{12.5,61.42},{16,56.81},{20,56.7},{25,57.62},{31.5,56.76},{40,63.88},{50,72.13},{63,76.55},{80,71.44},{100,61.58},{125,61.12},{160,52.84},{200,59.99},{250,58.84},{315,53.06},{400,55.39},{500,54.05},{630,52.82},{800,46.94},{1000,50.28},{1250.,54.56},{1600.,56.71},{2000,54.93},{2500.,52.53},{3150.,46.46},{4000,45.28},{5000,45.75},{6300.,45.14},{8000,42.27},{10000,43.35},{12500.,42.6},{16000,38.8},{20000,35.36}};
```

p[1] = Show[
Table[ListLogLinearPlot[data,
Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.002]}], {i, 1, Length[komodo]}],
PlotRange -> All]

Histogram[data]

Comment: A histogram is typically constructed with counts or relative frequencies.  What are the units of `data[[All,2]]`?  Those values sum to 1783.96.  Do you want a `BarChart` rather than a `Histogram`?

Comment: Actually, I am plotting the sound levels in dB vs frequency in Hz.  I don't know is it possible that if look at how both bar chart and histogram turn up and decide later?

Comment: I don't think a decision based on "I'll know it when I see it" should be satisfying.

Comment: Ok the standard practice in journal papers is to plot using the histogram.

Comment: Providing a journal example of what you want would get you more more targeted help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if something like this is what you’re after:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
  data,
  Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Thickness[0.02],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: simulated histogram]

Comment: The x-axis is cutting the histogram at the bottom. Is it possible to overcome that?

Comment: @acoustics see edit. You can apply any of the usual plot styling and formatting of course (colors, etc).

Comment: I tried changing the color but it is not happening. how to make it work

Comment: @acoustic Use something like ‘FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.02]]‘